# Listview with Filter won't refresh until keyboard is hidden or return is pressed

Tags: android, listview, filter

I have a listview which displays a list of contacts. I added an EditText to the layout above the listview so i can search using a Filter. I have implemented this using an onTextChanged Listener on the EditText. My listview adapter is a custom adapter which extends BaseAdapter and implements Filterable. My filter works and does the job correctly. The problem is, while i'm typing, the dataset gets refreshed but the listview itself doesn't refresh until i hide the keyboard or press the return key. If i try to click on the listview after i enter some text into the EditText but before i close the keyboard or press return, I get this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed 
but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of 
your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.
```

Now i'm definitely not modifying the content of the adapter from a thread other than the UI thread.

Could anyone explain what might be causing this problem?

Actually, I've found a workaround by calling `Activity.onContentChanged()` but i'm still curious as to why i actually need to refresh manually.

Comment: Are you calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` on the `Adapter`?

Comment: Yes I am. I've found a workaround but would still like to understand why the view itself doesn't automatically refresh.

Comment: The doesn't automatically refresh when just because the data in the datasource changes. You have to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on the `Adapter` to tell it that the data has changed.

Comment: I know, that's what i did, inside the Filter code


protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    

    list = (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>) results.values;    
notifyDataSetChanged();
    
((ContactActivity)ctx).onContentChanged();
   }

Comment: You are calling `onContentChanged()`? You shouldn't do that. `onContentChanged()` is just a hook which is called by the system after for example `setContentView()` is called. I think I  don't understand what exactly the problem is. I think if you post some code it will all become a lot clearer.

Comment: Are you directly modifying the displayed results dataset in `performFiltering()`?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes i am. Should i not do that?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. That should only be done in `publishResults()`. That's why your getting the background thread message in your error. `performFiltering()` is done in a separate thread.

Comment: same thing when i do it in publishResults()  
`protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {  
list = (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>) results.values;  
notifyDataSetChanged();  
}`

Comment: You're still getting the `IllegalStateException`, or it's not refreshing as expected? Either way, you'll need to share some code with us.

Comment: It's just not refreshing until i remove the keyboard or press the return key to add a new line. And it still gives me the exception if i write something and don't close the keyboard before clicking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have finally found a way to do this. The thing is, the dataset was refreshing when i call `notifyDataSetChanged();`, but the views weren't getting redrawn, I have no idea why (Could have something to do with me using the ViewHolder pattern maybe? Just a random guess...). So what i did is call `getListView().invalidateViews();` and the views get redrawn with the correct data.

Comment: Where did you put getListView().invalidateViews(); ?  I tried where I init the adapter in an Override in adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {}}; of the onChanged method and it hit there every time I'd search, but on a device that's showing the list not blocked by the keyboard, doesn't seem to work?

Comment: In my case, i put `getListView().invalidateViews();` inside a textwatcher's ontextchanged() method, as i was using an edittext to filter the list

Comment: you saved my precious time thnx bro :) ;)

Comment: Glad to know i've helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use setNotifyOnChange()  which automatically call notifyDataSetChanged(). it actually notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

Comment: I'm extending BaseAdapter. It seems like BaseAdapter doesn't implement this method.

Answer (score 0):

I had the some problem and I tried a lot of solutions without good result.

I solved this issu by adding `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in manifest file for my activity.

Try to use this solution it can help you