# RecyclerView doesn't Update until Soft Keyboard is Open/Close

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, refresh, updates

I have a **Posts Feed** (Something like Facebook News Feed) Activity and in it's layout I have an **EditText**, share **Button** at the top and a **RecyclerView** below it. The RecyclerView shows the Posts of all users by getting all the Posts from Server and binding data through Adapter in `OnCreate` Method.

When a User post something by typing some text in EditText and hit share Button, the data is sent to Server (I am using Retrofit) and upon Successful Response from Server I call the same function which call in `OnCreate` Method to show all Posts to update the RecyclerView.

The Problem I am facing is that the data is posted to Server, but the Layout only gets updated only when I press the back button to Hide/Close the Keyboard after typing or Show/Open the Keyboard by tapping the EditText.

Following is Some of the Code for better understanding:

**Here I Send Request to Server when User Post something:**

```
Call<CreatePost> call = mAPIService.sharePost(apiKey, post_description);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<CreatePost>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<CreatePost> call, @NonNull Response<CreatePost> response) {
                boolean error = response.body().getError();
                if (!error) {
                    displayFeedPosts();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<CreatePost> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

**Here Is displayFeedPosts Method:**

```
private void displayFeedPosts() {
        Call<FeedPosts> call = mAPIService.displayFeedPosts(apiKey);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<FeedPosts>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<FeedPosts> call, @NonNull Response<FeedPosts> response) {
                boolean error = response.body().getError();
                if (!error) {
                    ArrayList<Post> feedPosts = response.body().getPosts();
                    for (Post post : feedPosts) {
                        mTripFeedPostUserNames.add(post.getFirstName() + " " + post.getLastName());
                        mTripFeedPostTime.add(post.getPostDatetime());
                        mTripFeedPostContent.add(post.getPostDescription());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<FeedPosts> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });

        initRecyclerView();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.trip_feed_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mTripFeedPostRecyclerViewAdapter = new TripFeedPostRecyclerViewAdapter(this, mTripFeedPostProfileImages, mTripFeedPostUserNames, mTripFeedPostTime, mTripFeedPostContent, mTripFeedPostImages, mTripFeedPostID);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mTripFeedPostRecyclerViewAdapter);
    }
```

**PS: I am new to Android, I apologise if I have done things the wrong way. Your suggestions are Welcomed.**

**Note: The same Question has been asked regarding ListView [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217317/listview-does-not-update-until-keyboard-is-hidden) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184931/listview-with-filter-wont-refresh-until-keyboard-is-hidden-or-return-is-pressed) but it doesn't solved my problem**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the above problem with the help of [Arsalan Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52496890/5631594) Answer.

Actually the `initRecyclerView()` was not executing outside the `onResponse()` method. Including it inside the `onResponse()` method and using `notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of `initRecyclerView()` solved the problem.

The solution to data being populated twice I solved it by modifying the  `displayFeedPosts()` in the following way:

```
private void updateFeedPosts() {
        Call<FeedPosts> call = mAPIService.displayFeedPosts(apiKey);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<FeedPosts>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<FeedPosts> call, @NonNull Response<FeedPosts> response) {
                boolean error = response.body().getError();
                if (!error) {
                    mTripFeedPostProfileImages.clear();
                    mTripFeedPostUserNames.clear();
                    mTripFeedPostTime.clear();
                    mTripFeedPostContent.clear();
                    mTripFeedPostImages.clear();
                    mTripFeedPostID.clear();
                    mTripFeedPostRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    ArrayList<Post> feedPosts = response.body().getPosts();
                    for (Post post : feedPosts) {
                        mTripFeedPostProfileImages.add(post.getProfilePicture());
                        mTripFeedPostUserNames.add(post.getFirstName() + " " + post.getLastName());
                        mTripFeedPostTime.add(post.getPostDatetime());
                        mTripFeedPostContent.add(post.getPostDescription());
                        mTripFeedPostImages.add(post.getPostImagePath());
                        mTripFeedPostID.add(post.getPostTripfeedId());
                    }
                    mTripFeedPostRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<FeedPosts> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

I cleared the **Adapter Data** before populating it again with updated data.
I hope my answer will help someone having the same problem.

**PS:** I know I am not using my Adapter Model in correct way, I can use only one `ArrayList` for all the values, I'll modify it later right now I am focusing on the main functions.

Answer (score 0):

should call initRecyclerView here:

```
private void displayFeedPosts() {
        Call<FeedPosts> call = mAPIService.displayFeedPosts(apiKey);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<FeedPosts>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<FeedPosts> call, @NonNull Response<FeedPosts> response) {
                boolean error = response.body().getError();
                if (!error) {
                    ArrayList<Post> feedPosts = response.body().getPosts();
                    for (Post post : feedPosts) {
                        mTripFeedPostUserNames.add(post.getFirstName() + " " + post.getLastName());
                        mTripFeedPostTime.add(post.getPostDatetime());
                        mTripFeedPostContent.add(post.getPostDescription());
                    }
               initRecyclerView();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<FeedPosts> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

private void initRecyclerView() {
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.trip_feed_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mTripFeedPostRecyclerViewAdapter = new TripFeedPostRecyclerViewAdapter(this, mTripFeedPostProfileImages, mTripFeedPostUserNames, mTripFeedPostTime, mTripFeedPostContent, mTripFeedPostImages, mTripFeedPostID);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mTripFeedPostRecyclerViewAdapter);
        mTripFeedPostRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @arsalan-khan but this one populates the RecyclerView twice. I found a solution I am posting it as an answer, It may help someone having similar problem.